# Countable union of clopen sets is clopen?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the countable union (or intersection) of clopen sets clopen? I understand that the countable union of these sets must be closed, must it be open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Any** union of open sets is open. A countable union of clopen sets need not be closed, however. Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, with the topology that it inherits from the real line. Then $\left\{\frac1n\right\}$ is a clopen set in $X$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, but $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left\{\frac1n\right\}=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is not closed (and hence not clopen) in $X$: its closure is all of $X$.

Comment: I miswrote! I meant to say that I knew it must be open but I couldn't say it was closed, but this example helped illustrate why that is. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasMart: You’re welcome. I was hoping that you’d simply had a mental hiccup when you wrote *closed* instead of *open*. :-)